# Angular.copy inside promise with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope, angular-promise

I need to make a copy of an object, but this object is inside a promise.
When I modify the object a, the object b is modified too.
I know that it can be due to **async** mode with promise, but I can not figure out it.

Simplifying my code, I have something like this:

The promise:

```
$scope.search = function () {
    DocumentFactory.getDocuments(dataParams).then(function (data) {
      makeFacets(data);
    },
    function (data) {
      $scope.errorMessages.search = true;
    });
};
```

It will search into many topics and will return some of them.
Then I create an array with that topics:

```
var makeFacets = function(data) {
  $scope.topics=[]; 
  $scope.topics[0] ={father: "General", label:""};
  $scope.topics[1] ={father: "International", label:""};
  $scope.topics[2] ={father: "Crime", label:""};
  $scope.topics[3] ={father: "NonLegal", label:""};
  [...]
};
```

Once I have the object, I use it to show that topics and also to filter inside that topics:

```
 <div class="filter-box">
   <input type="input" class="form-control" ng-model="filter.topic" ng-change="test1()">
 </div>
 <div class="filter-name" ng-repeat="data in topics">
    <span>{{data.label}}</span>
 </div>
```

My last step is try to filter inside that topics, to do that, I need to make a copy of the topics.

```
$scope.allTopics = [];
$scope.test1 = function(){
  if($scope.allTopics.length === 0){
    angular.copy($scope.topics, $scope.allTopics);
  }
  $scope.topics = $scope.allTopics;
  var filter = $scope.filter.topic;
  if(filter.length>=3){   
    for(var i = 0; i<$scope.topics.length; i++){
      if($scope.topics[i].children !== undefined){
        for(var j = 0; j<$scope.topics[i].children.length; j++){
          if($scope.topics[i].children[j].label.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter.toLowerCase()) === -1){
              $scope.topics[i].children.splice(j, 1);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

This is not working, of course. I have tried a lot of things more but no one is working.

Also I have tried to add the copy here:

```
$scope.search = function () {
    DocumentFactory.getDocuments(dataParams).then(function (data) {
      makeFacets(data);
      $scope.allTopics = [];
      angular.copy($scope.topics, $scope.allTopics);
    },
    function (data) {
      $scope.errorMessages.search = true;
    });
};
```

All time I modify the topics object, the all Topics object is also modified.

Comment: In your test1 function after you do the copy - why do you assign `allTopics` back to `topics` (`$scope.topics = $scope.allTopics;`)? After this line they will have the same identity again and your copy operation was useless... do not assign them to each other!

Comment: OMG! @MichaelRose stupid me... I just needed to put angular.copy($scope.allTopics, $scope.topics);  instead '='. Thanks you!

Comment: great, posted it as an answer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you are doing an assignment after calling `copy`. Thus, the two variables reference the same object leading to the problem you observe. Just leave out the assignment after you have copied it or do a copy instead of an assignment.

```
if($scope.allTopics.length === 0){
   angular.copy($scope.topics, $scope.allTopics);
}
$scope.topics = $scope.allTopics; // <-- this assignment is wrong
```

Note you can also use copy in a more assignment-like fashion:

```
$scope.topics = angular.copy($scope.allTopics);
```